# How to delete JSON keys when editing account?

Tags: php, json

When a user edits his/her own account, if his/her existing account was with email should be able to update it to `phonenumber` and vice versa.

What I thought is to check for the format of the input and if the input is an `email` and the old one was a `phonenumber` then delete the key with the `phonenumber` and create a new with the `email` else just update the `email` key´s value. And the same story with the `phonenumber`.

The array below are my users in the users.txt file.

```
   [

    {
        "role": "admin",
        "id": "59df4ef2d8d39",
        "email": "a@a.dk",
        "name": "A",
        "lastname": "A",
        "password": "1",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfb91515810.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59df4f1b070e6",
        "phonenumber": "12345678",
        "name": "B",
        "lastname": "B",
        "password": "2",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59e37de69475b.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc0cb07985",
        "email": "c@c.dk",
        "name": "C",
        "lastname": "C",
        "password": "3",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc0cb06c5f.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc22f26f78",
        "phonenumber": "87654321",
        "name": "D",
        "lastname": "D",
        "password": "4",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc22f2638d.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc460b261e",
        "email": "e@e.dk",
        "name": "E",
        "lastname": "E",
        "password": "5",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc460af866.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59e75231a393c",
        "email": "x@x.dk",
        "name": "Y",
        "lastname": "Y",
        "password": "",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59e79184d0335."
    }
]
```

And this is the PHP API where the update is handled.

```
  //GETTING FROM FILE:
    $sajUsers = file_get_contents('users.txt');
    $ajUsers = json_decode($sajUsers);

    //_________________________________________________________//


    // getting it from the front end:
    $sUserId = $_POST['txtUpdateUserId'];
    $sNewUserRole = $_POST['txtUpdateUserRole'];
    $sNewUserName = $_POST['txtUpdateUserName'];
    $sNewUserLastName = $_POST['txtUpdateUserLastName'];
    $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber = $_POST['txtUpdateUserEmailorPhoneNumber'];
    $sNewUserPassword = $_POST['txtUpdateUserPassword'];

    //_________________________________________________________//


    $match_found = false;
    //The is getting it from the database.
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $ajUsers ); $i++ ) {  
         if ( $sUserId  == $ajUsers[$i]->id ) { //checks if the value of the username is equal to the value in the array.
            $ajUsers[$i]->role = $sNewUserRole;
            if ( fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ) ) {          // call the function which checks if is a valid email
                 if ( $ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber ) {

                     //HOW TO DELETE THE RESPECTIVE PHONENUMBER KEY 

                     $ajUsers[$i]->email = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber; //AND INSTEAD ASSIGN AN EMAIL KEY
                 }

                 else {

                     $ajUsers[$i]->email = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;
                 }
            } 
              else if ( fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ) {  // call the function which checks that it should only                                                                     contain digits
                 if ( $ajUsers[$i]->email ) {

                           //HOW TO DELETE THE RESPECTIVE EMAIL KEY
                      $ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;

                     }      
                 else {

                     $ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;
                 }
            }
            $ajUsers[$i]->name = $sNewUserName;
            $ajUsers[$i]->lastname = $sNewUserLastName;
            $ajUsers[$i]->password = $sNewUserPassword;
            $ajUsers[$i]->image = $sNewUserImageUrl;
            $match_found = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    //_________________________________________________________//


    if( $match_found ) {

        //PUTTING TO FILE:
        $sajNewUsers = json_encode( $ajUsers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE  );
        file_put_contents('users.txt', $sajNewUsers);

        echo $sjResponse = '{"update":"ok"}';
        exit; //end the if statement and exit if it works.
    }

    else {
            echo $sjResponse = '{"update":"error"}'; // it didnt work.
            exit;
         }

    //_________________________________________________________//


    function fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ){ //checks if the property is valid. Called in line 6.
        $sNewUserEmail = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;
        if ( !filter_var( $sNewUserEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ){
            return false; // returns false if its not valid. Then it wont run the if.
        }
        return true; // else it will run the signin.
    }

    function fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ){ //checks if the property is valid. Called in line 6.
        $sNewUserPhoneNumber = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;
        if ( !preg_match( "/^[0-99]+$/", $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ){
            return false; // returns false if its not valid. Then it wont run the if.
        }
        return true; // else it will run the signin.
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you save all your userdetails in a textfile like that? With the password in plain text to?

Comment: it´s just for dummy not a real project yet.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need, and are asking for in your code at the comments of:

> // HOW TO DELETE THE RESPECTIVE PHONENUMBER KEY
>   and 
>   // HOW TO DELETE THE RESPECTIVE EMAIL KEY

It may be as simple as:

```
unset($ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber);
// and 
unset($ajUsers[$i]->email);
// respectively
```

If thats what you were looking for.

Comment: that is actually what I am asking for, however I am not 100% sure that the overall solution is good logically for what I want to do. What do you think?

Comment: Guess it depends entirely. I mean, if you want to remove those keys, unset is a good way to nix them completely (gone, finito). But if you wanted to keep the keys, but have them empty, then you would not use unset, but rather assign them to null.

Answer (score 1):

Decode `$sajUsers` into an array of associative array by passing a truthy boolean argument to json_decode.

```
$ajUsers = json_decode($sajUsers, true);
```

Then loop over `$ajUsers` making sure that the pointer to `$user` is a reference by prepending an ampersand.

```
foreach($ajUsers as $key=>&$user)
{
    if($user['id'] == $sUserId) 
    {
        $match_found = true;

        if(fnCheckEmailFormat($sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber))
        {
            $user['email'] = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;
            unset($user['phonenumber']);
            continue;
        }

        if(fnCheckDigitFormat($sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber))
        {
            $user['phonenumber'] = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;
            unset($user['email']);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an associative array for this? Could you explain me, as I have never used them before.

Comment: My bad. I mean an array of arrays. You've already been using associative arrays. PHP arrays are key-value maps. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: The important part in this answer is using a 'reference' on the loop, so you can directly unset the key you dont need through that reference. While the other way, you have to access the original array variable with the right index and sub key to unset (like in my answer). I personally Like this answer better, as references reduces memory overhead and makes for cleaner code.